# Create ConfiguRule with multiple tags in Scope

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, config

I'm using Cloudformation to create a  ConfigRule that lists all unencrypted volumes and only volumes with some tags:

```
Resources:
  EncryptedVolumesConfigRule:
    Type: AWS::Config::ConfigRule
    Properties: 
      ConfigRuleName:
       !Join
         - '-'
         - - "infr"
           - !Ref RegionCode
           - !Ref Env
           - "encrypted-volumes"
      Scope:
        ComplianceResourceTypes:
          - "AWS::EC2::Volume"
        TagKey: "environment"
        TagValue: !Ref Env
        TagKey: "hostname"
      Description: "A Config rule that checks whether the EBS volumes that are in an attached state are encrypted."
      Source:
        Owner: "AWS"
        SourceIdentifier: "ENCRYPTED_VOLUMES"
```

When I tried the above configuration, I get this error:

```
Scope cannot be applied to both resource and tag (Service: AmazonConfig; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException;
```

What I want to do here is to list all volumes with tags environment:env and hostname tag not empty. Is it actually possible ? If not is there any workaround ?
Thank you.